# Calling Function at Random and Passing to Variable in Python

Tags: python

I have some functions that I want to call at random. They are Test1, Test2, Test3 and Test4.

I can achieve this by doing the following:

```
test_list = [Test1, Test2, Test3, Test4]
random.choice(test_list)()
```

However I also want to pass the function name to another variable called `resultx`. How can I do this so the same name of the randomly-chosen function is passed to the variable?

Comment: Do you really want the *name* of the function, rather than the function itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following :

```
from random import choice

def fn1():
    return 'fn1 called'

def fn2():
    return 'fn2 called'

funcs = [fn1, fn2]

random_func = choice(funcs)
random_func_name = random_func.__name__
print(random_func_name, random_func())
```

`.__name__` will give you the function's name.

Answer (score -1):

You can assign the output of `random.choice` first to `resultx` and then call it or perform operations on it accordingly

```
import random

def Test1():
  print('Test1')

def Test2():
  print('Test2')

def Test3():
  print('Test3')

test_list = [Test1, Test2, Test3]

#  <function __main__.Test#()> gets assigned to resultx 
resultx = random.choice(test_list)

# Returns function name
resultx_name = resultx .__name__

resultx() # Returns 'Test#'
```

Answer (score -1):

You can assign variable directly to random.choice()

```
test_list = [Test1, Test2, Test3, Test4]
resultx = random.choice(test_list)
```

Or you can assign different variable to function and call it wherever is necessary.

```
test_list = [Test1, Test2, Test3, Test4]
a = random.choice(test_list)
resultx = a
```

Comment: I'm writing to you to notify you that I have already posted this answer, please read all answers before posting your own.

Comment: Sorry, did not load the page before posting.